# Dir-Content to array - exclude files with specific pattern

Tags: php, regex, scandir

I would like to collect all files in a specific directory (at the moment I'm using scandir) - but only those, who do not have a special pattern.

Example:

```
someimage.png
someimage-150x150.png
someimage-233x333.png
someotherimage.png
someotherimage-760x543.png
someotherimage-150x50.png
```

In this case I would like to get someimage.png and someotherimage.png as result in my array.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the special pattern ? A lot of different regex could work with your example.

Answer (score 0):

To get array of filenames consisting of letters only, you can use this:

```
$array = array();
$handle = opendir($directory);
while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
    if(preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]+\.png$/',$file)){
      $array[] = $file;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will fill `$correctFiles` with all png images that don't contain dimensions (`42x42` for example) in their names.

```
<?php

// here you get the files with scandir, or any method you want
$files = array(
    'someimage.png',
    'someimage-150x150.png',
    'someimage-233x333.png',
    'someotherimage.png',
    'someotherimage-760x543.png',
    'someotherimage-150x50.png'
);

$correctFiles = array(); // This will contain the correct file names
foreach ($files as $file)
    if (!preg_match('/^.*-\d+x\d+\.png$/', $file)) // If the file doesn't have "NUMBERxNUMBER" in their name
        $correctFiles[] = $file;

print_r($correctFiles); // Here you can do what you want with those files
```

If you don't want to store the names in an array (faster, less memory consumption), you can use the code below.

```
<?php

// here you get the files with scandir, or any method you want
$files = array(
    'someimage.png',
    'someimage-150x150.png',
    'someimage-233x333.png',
    'someotherimage.png',
    'someotherimage-760x543.png',
    'someotherimage-150x50.png'
);

foreach ($files as $file)
    if (!preg_match('/^.*-\d+x\d+\.png$/', $file)) // If the file doesn't have "NUMBERxNUMBER" in their name
    {
        print_r($file); // Here you can do what you want with this file
    }
```

Comment: Hi there and thank you. I always get PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in  gen4.php on line 15...  This is if (!preg_match('/^.*-\d+x\d+\.png$/'))...

Comment: Ah, I mentioned that I have to add a second argument, in this case $file. I also mentioned, that I get wrong returns if a file is called test.123-215x215.png or something like that (if there is a number in front of the "-").

Comment: Hi, sorry, I wrote this answer too fast and forgot the 2nd argument. I have corrected this error.
The code should now work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The OOP way could be to use a DirectoryIterator in combination with a FilterIterator:

```
class FilenameFilter extends FilterIterator {

    protected $filePattern;

    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator , $pattern) {
        parent::__construct($iterator);
        $this->filePattern = $pattern;
    }

    public function accept() {
        $currentFile = $this->current();
        return (1 === preg_match($this->filePattern, $currentFile));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$myFilter = new FilenameFilter(new DirectoryIterator('path/to/your/files'), '/^[a-z-_]*\.(png|PNG|jpg|JPG)$/i');
foreach ($myFilter as $filteredFile) {
    // Only files which match your specified pattern should appear here
    var_dump($filteredFile);
}
```

It's just an idea and the code is not tested but. Hope that helps;

Answer (score 0):

```
    $files = array(
        "someimage.png",
        "someimage-150x150.png",
        "someimage-233x333.png",
        "someotherimage.png",
        "someotherimage-760x543.png",
        "someotherimage-150x50.png",
    );
    foreach ( $files as $key => $value ) {
        if ( preg_match( '@\-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$@', $value ) ) {
            unset( $files[$key] );
        }
    }
    echo '<xmp>' . print_r( $files, 1 ) . '</xmp>';
```

Comment: Hi and thank you very much. In this case I still get values like "123-1-123-12345-0.TEST_-250x250.jpg"

Comment: I mentioned it some minutes ago - thank you very much. It works like a charm :-)